# Help using 2 parameters to output a specific category

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I'm looking to be able to enter an "AGE" and a "V02" in a formula that tells me what "category" the person would be in ie; good, excellent, etc.

[image: google sheets snapshot]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(I2, {VLOOKUP(I1, A2:G, {2,3,4,5,6,7}, 1); B1:G1}, 2, 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: THANK YOU so Much, I've spent a minimum of 3 days working out different formulas!!!